Desktop application for Electron and vuejs
I have a BeginTestView.vue page that has a start testing button. Clicking this button launches an exe file with Nunit tests in C#.
I tried to run the exe file using child_process in the Vue component, but I get the error:
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'child_process' in 'C:\.....

However, if you run this exe file from the main process when launching the application, everything works fine. How can I use child_process in Vue itself?
Sample code:
<script setup>
//import { execFile } from 'child_process'
function beginTest(){
  const execFile = require('child_process')
    execFile("./testexe/TestConsole.exe", (error, stdout, stderr) => {
  
      if (error) {
         console.error(`Error executing the file: ${error.message} dirname:${__dirname}`);
         return;
      }
      console.log(`File executed successfully: ${stdout}`);
    });
  }
</script>

<template>
    <div class="content">
        <button class="button" @click="beginTest">Begin test</button>
    </div>
</template>

<style scoped lang="scss">
...
</style>


Note that Vue runs at the client-side (aka the browser) even though you are using Electron. You can't use child_process in the browser environment.
You can use IPC to let the Node.js process (main.js) do that.

I think that there could be a way to still communicate between Electron and Vue, so run the Node function on the backend and throw it to the frontend.

@kissu Yes, that is what IPC do
